# Getting connection timed out error in Java microservice

Tags: spring, spring-boot, postman, microservices

I have built a microservice using Java 8 and SpringBoot 2. From this microservice, I'm trying to consume another REST API service. However, I'm getting the following error on Chrome

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The underlying HTTP client completed
>   without emitting a response.
>
> 2018-06-12 15:21:29.300 ERROR 17996 --- [ctor-http-nio-3]
>   .a.w.r.e.DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler : Failed to handle request
>   [GET http://localhost:8080/category/search]
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection
>   timed out: no further information: test.usdemo.xyz.com/92.54.41.24:443
>                   at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
>                   at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_171]
>                   at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:325)
>   ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
>                   at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340)
>   ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
>                   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:633)
>   ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
>                   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
>   ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
>                   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
>   ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
>                   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
>   ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
>                   at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
>   ~[netty-common-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
>                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_171] Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed
>   out: no further information
>                   ... 10 common frames omitted

I'm able to consume the same service successfully using PostMan but not through my microservice.

Please assist to advise on this.

Comment: We need some more info. Can you post some code snippets of your service accessing the other service?

Comment: [Additional details] I have already disabled the firewall.

Comment: we need some code, can you please post the controller you are trying to access and the call you are doing from your microservice?

Comment: Without any code, there is little chance that someone can help you out. Please post some code and where exactly does the timeout occur

Comment: Code snippet for reference as follows:-

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to edit my own question above as I do not see the edit option hence I'm adding the additional details here to get the resolution of my query.

**Controller class:-**

```
@RestController
```

public class CategorySearchController {

```
private final CategorySearchService categorySearchService;

@Autowired
public CategorySearchController(CategorySearchService categorySearchService) {
    this.categorySearchService = categorySearchService;
}


@GetMapping(path = "/search-category")
public Mono<CategoryResponse> searchCategories(SearchRequest categorySearchRequest){
    return categorySearchService
            .searchCategories()
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(
                    new EntityNotFoundException("No category matching " + categorySearchRequest.getSearchTerm() + " was found")));
}
```

}

**Service class:-**

```
@Service
public class CategorySearchServiceImpl implements CategorySearchService {
    private String baseUrl = "https://demo0954903.mockable.io";

    @Override
    public Mono<CategoryResponse> searchCategories() {
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(baseUrl);
        return webClient.
                 get()
                .uri("/category-search")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(CategoryResponse.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this issue. I need to add the proxy in the webclient as follows:-

```
private final WebClient webClient;
ReactorClientHttpConnector connector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(
                options -> options.httpProxy(addressSpec -> {
                return addressSpec.host(PROXY_HOST).port(PROXY_PORT);
                }));

        this.webClient = webClientBuilder.baseUrl(BASE_URL).clientConnector(connector).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your proxy settings. In Spring applications, you can add the following to the VM arguments to set your proxy: -Dhttp.proxyHost=your.proxy.net -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080

Answer (score 0):

I met a similar issue on a scala project. According to the error message, I found IntelliJ took Ant as the compiler which I was expected sbt as the compiler.

Solve the issue by turn on sbt shell use for builds option (Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > sbt > sbt projects > sbt shell > check builds )

```
Executing pre-compile tasks...
Loading Ant configuration...
Running Ant tasks...
Abnormal build process termination: 
{remove some sensitive logs here}
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Operation timed out: /127.0.0.1:50154
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:716)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:707)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exiting.
Executing post-compile tasks...
Loading Ant configuration...
Running Ant tasks...
Synchronizing output directories...
2021/9/15, 8:52 AM - Build completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 27 sec, 726 ms
```